# neo4j serverplugin on OSX

Tags: neo4j

Trying to write a ServerPlugin but it does not seems to get loaded.
The 'extensions' list from 'curl http://localhost:7474/db/data' keeps empty.

Followed this guide: [32.1 Server Plugins](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html)
Jar created with a Maven project (compile target 1.7). Jar contents:

```
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:34 CET 2015 META-INF/
 130 Mon Dec 28 21:52:32 CET 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:30 CET 2015 eu/
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:30 CET 2015 eu/diversit/
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:30 CET 2015 eu/diversit/neo4j/
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:30 CET 2015 eu/diversit/neo4j/plugins/
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:28 CET 2015 META-INF/services/
 977 Mon Dec 28 21:52:30 CET 2015 eu/diversit/neo4j/plugins/CamelCasePlugin.class
3336 Mon Dec 28 21:52:30 CET 2015 eu/diversit/neo4j/plugins/GetAll.class
  75 Mon Dec 28 21:52:28 CET 2015 META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:34 CET 2015 META-INF/maven/
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:34 CET 2015 META-INF/maven/eu.diversit.neo4j.plugins/
   0 Mon Dec 28 21:52:34 CET 2015 META-INF/maven/eu.diversit.neo4j.plugins/camel-case-plugin/
1847 Mon Dec 28 21:20:38 CET 2015 META-INF/maven/eu.diversit.neo4j.plugins/camel-case-plugin/pom.xml
 134 Mon Dec 28 21:52:32 CET 2015 META-INF/maven/eu.diversit.neo4j.plugins/camel-case-plugin/pom.properties
```

Contents of META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin:

```
eu.diversit.neo4j.plugins.CamelCasePlugin
eu.diversit.neo4j.plugins.GetAll
```

The CamelCasePlugin is my own plugin and GetAll is from the examples.
Both do not get discovered.

I have feeling the '/Application/Neo4j Community Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins' folder is not on classpath at all (on Mac at least).
However, putting the jar in the bundled jre's lib/ext folder or in the '/Application/Neo4j Community Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin' folder, which both are on the library path, also did not work.

Also, on Mac, I cannot find the 'console.log' file or 'neo4j' application to start the server it from command-line.
The 'messages.log' in '~/Documents/Neo4j//' folder does not show anything about plugins.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have to tried to call the plugin URL? Maybe something is wrong with discovery. Another idea is to retry with the .tar.gz artifact from http://neo4j.com/downloads

Comment: Just tried the Linux distro and the plugin loads just fine in that release.
So the issue is related to the OSX disto only.
I'll try to make a bug issue for this.